# Deploying an OpenAPI-based API gateway via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I was given a link to an OpenAPI 3.0.1 definition hosted on SwaggerHub, and was told to deploy it. On the Terraform side, I see way too many resources that confuse me, I'm not sure which one to use. What's the most straightforward way to deploy an API gateway via Terraform that's already all configured in an OpenAPI definition? Is there a resource that would simply let me provide an OpenAPI definition URL to the API gateway, or would I have to copy paste the actual JSON somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenAPI providers?

Comment: I haven't, what do they do?

Comment: Ok actually my original assumption is correct: you need to develop a provider for this, and can leverage https://github.com/dikhan/terraform-provider-openapi. Also, is this api gateway with swagger spec hosted on another platform e.g. AWS?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this straightforward? Doesn't Terraform natively support resources for this? Also, that provider doesn't support openapi 3.

Comment: When you say "SwaggerHub", do you mean the SwaggerHub web app https://app.swaggerhub.com, or do you mean an OpenAPI YAML/JSON file like [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v3.0/api-with-examples.yaml)?

Comment: I apologize, I guess my lack of knowledge is showing. Yes, it's that first one, OpenAPI YAML/JSON, but it's hosted on SwaggerHub? I mean, I access it from SwaggerHub, but it's in the OpenAPI format you posted. Don't know anything about SwaggerHub, I just guessed it's like GitHub but for API.

Comment: SwaggerHub is not an API gateway, nor does it host API gateways. It hosts OpenAPI definition files (info about an API's endpoints), not the APIs themselves. I got confused by the wording, that's all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AWS API Gateway service has two main usage patterns:

1. Directly specify individual resources, methods, requests, integrations, and responses as individual objects in the API Gateway API.
2. Submit an OpenAPI definition of the entire API as a single unit and have API Gateway itself split that out into all of the separate objects in API Gateway's data model.

Since the underlying API supports both models, it can be hard to see initially which parts are relevant to each usage pattern. The Terraform provider for AWS follows the underlying API design, and so that confusion appears there too.

It sounds like you are intending to take the second path I described above, in which case the definition in Terraform is *comparatively* straightforward, and in particular it typically involves only a single Terraform resource to define the API itself. (You may need to use others to "deploy" the API, etc, but that seems outside of the scope of your current question.)

[The `api_gateway_rest_api` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api) is the root resource type for defining an API Gateway REST API, and for the OpenAPI approach is the only one required to define your entire API surface, by specifying the OpenAPI definition in its `body` argument:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name = "example"
  body = file("${path.module}/openapi.json")
}
```

In the above example I've assumed that you've saved the API definition in JSON format in an `openapi.json` file in the same directory as the `.tf` file which would contain the resource configuration. I'm not familiar with SwaggerHub, but if there is a Terraform provider available for it which has a data source for retrieving the definition directly from that system then you could potentially combine those, but the principle would be the same; it would only be the exact expression for the `body` argument that would change.

The other approach with the resources/etc defined explicitly via the API Gateway API would have a separate resource for each of API Gateway's separate object types describing an API, which makes for a much more complicated Terraform configuration. However, none of those need be used (and indeed, none *should* be used, to avoid conflicts) when you have defined your API using an OpenAPI specification.

---

NOTE: The above is about API Gateway REST APIs, which is a separate offering from "API Gateway v2", which offers so-called "HTTP APIs" and "WebSocket APIs". As far as I know, API Gateway v2 doesn't support OpenAPI definitions and therefore I've assumed you're asking about the original API Gateway, and thus "REST APIs".